# Elasticsearch 1.7.4 log rotation

Tags: elasticsearch, logrotate

I'm trying to use logging.yml ( Elasticsearch file ) + logrotate configuration for elasticsearch log rotation .

**Information :**

1 . Elasticsearch version - 1.7.4

2. I don't want to keep any rotated files ...

Configuration :

**logging.yml configuration :**

```
 file:
    type: org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender 
    file: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log
    rollingPolicy: org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
    rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern: ${path.logs}/${cluster.name}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz
    layout:
      type: pattern
      conversionPattern: "[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %m%n"
```

**Logrotate configuration :**

```
/var/log/elasticsearch/*.log {
    daily
    rotate 0
    copytruncate
    compress
    delaycompress
    missingok
    notifempty
    maxage 0 
    create 644 elasticsearch elasticsearch
}
```

More details :

Running ls on /var/log/elasticsearch :

```
total 20K
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 18763 Jul  4 08:46 dba01es.d1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     0 Jun 19 10:01 dba01es.d1_index_indexing_slowlog.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     0 Jun 19 10:01 dba01es.d1_index_search_slowlog.log
```

Running manually logrotate :

```
logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.d/elasticsearch
```

logrotate output :

```
 reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/elasticsearch
reading config info for /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log 

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/elasticsearch/*.log  forced from command line (no old logs will be kept)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log
  log needs rotating
considering log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1_index_indexing_slowlog.log
  log does not need rotating
considering log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1_index_search_slowlog.log
  log does not need rotating
rotating log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log, log->rotateCount is 0
dateext suffix '-20160704'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
previous log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.1 does not exist
renaming /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.1.gz to /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.2.gz (rotatecount 1, logstart 1, i 1), 
old log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.1.gz does not exist
renaming /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.0.gz to /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.1.gz (rotatecount 1, logstart 1, i 0), 
old log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.0.gz does not exist
log /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.2.gz doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
copying /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log to /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log.1
truncating /var/log/elasticsearch/dba01es.d1.log
```

Running ll after running logrotate manually :

```
total 32K
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     0 Jul  4 08:48 dba01es.d1.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch 28937 Jul  4 08:48 dba01es.d1.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     0 Jun 19 10:01 dba01es.d1_index_indexing_slowlog.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 elasticsearch elasticsearch     0 Jun 19 10:01 dba01es.d1_index_search_slowlog.log
```

My question are :

1. Why the dba01es.d1.log.1 file is not compressed ?
2. Why the rotate 0 is not working here ? and logrotate keep saving the rotate file ....

Thanks a lot !
Amit